# T-SQL SUM by Three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've created an SqlFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9363f/4 to explain my problem

I have three entities "Invoice"->1:n->"Payment"->1:n->"Taking"

Each entity has it's own Total (amount), i have to write a SELECT that sums the amount (of each entity) to match the ampount of the parent... The problem is on the "Payments" that are replied for each Taking.

```
SELECT I.invoice_number AS invoiceNumber, I.amount AS invoiceAmount, SUM(P.amount) AS paymentAmount, SUM(T.amount) as takingAmount 
FROM Invoice AS I
INNER JOIN Payment AS P ON P.invoice_number = I.invoice_number
INNER JOIN Taking AS T ON T.invoice_number = P.invoice_number AND T.payment_row = P.payment_row
GROUP BY I.invoice_number, I.amount, P.invoice_number
```

Result is (first row wrong)

```
invoiceNumber   invoiceAmount   paymentAmount   takingAmount
1               100.2           300.4           100.2
2               98.4            98.4            98.4
```

How can i group this one avoiding the "amount" of the Payments "replyed"

**[EDITED]**
Result Expected

```
invoiceNumber   invoiceAmount   paymentAmount   takingAmount
1               100.2           100.2           100.2
2               98.4            98.4            98.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write your query with two subqueries to calculate Payment and Taking amounts.

Your query will be:

```
 SELECT I.invoice_number, SUM(I.amount),
     (SELECT SUM(P.amount)
     FROM Payment P
     WHERE P.invoice_number = I.Invoice_number) as Payment_Amount,
     (SELECT SUM(T.amount)
     FROM Taking T
     WHERE T.invoice_number = I.Invoice_number) as Taking_Amount
 FROM Invoice I
 group by I.invoice_number
```

Here the [**Sql Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9363f/14/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` operator:

```
SELECT I.invoice_number AS invoiceNumber, I.amount AS invoiceAmount, 
       p.paymentAmount, t.takingAmount 
FROM Invoice AS I cross apply (
    select SUM(amount) as paymentAmount
    from Payment 
    where invoice_number =  i.invoice_number
) p cross apply (
   select SUM(amount) as takingAmount
   from Taking as takingAmount
   where invoice_number =  i.invoice_number
) t;
```

Your `joins` has some redundant filtration, so would produced in-consistence   sums